# How to download a resized version of an image with glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a recycler view which consists of a grid of images. This is the code I sue to load said images.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ShowHolder holder, int position) {
        Item current = mItems.get(position);

        String imageUrl = current .getUrl();
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imageUrl).into(holder.mImageView);
    }
```

The problem is that the images can be of varying sizes, so Glide takes more time to load some images rather than others. Instead I want every image to be downloaded in the same resolution, thus reducing downlaod time and data usage.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: why you dont change mImageView size as Glide fill this image only , or override method override(600, 200) --> as Nougat Lover said

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this:

Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imageUrl)

.override(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel)

.centerCrop() // this cropping technique scales the image

.into(holder.mImageView);

Comment: Are you sure this actually affects the downloaded image? It seems like this first download the image in its original size, then it resizes it.

Comment: This will help you achieve what you want: [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-module-example-optimizing-by-loading-images-in-custom-sizes)