# changing sizes of images when using glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I use glide library for download image from server but when images loaded their size become change although I use scaleType= fitXY !!
this is my method that I use for download images.
thanks for any suggestion.

```
public void DownloadImage(ImageView imageView , final String url){
    if (HM_Images.containsKey(url)) {
        GlideDrawable bitmap = HM_Images.get(url);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
    } else {
        Glide
                .with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(url)
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        try {
                            HM_Images.put(url, resource);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Comment: see this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39918117/2919483

Comment: I used it before but it didn't work!